# How can I format an rsync -exclude-from file so it excludes files/dirs but includes others in the same path

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

There are lots of online howto's for rsync, but after days of struggling, reading the man page repeatedly and hacking away at a exclude-from file, I need a hand.

I have created a custom local init script which loads the root filesystem into ram, and to support this environment I built a utility named ramsync which does a rsync between / (in ram) and / on the "backing" disk. This all went swimmingly when I just wanted to only exclude many paths and their contents. I've been using this system for some time w/o a hitch, but after reading more about rsync, I wanted to expand the utility to have an easily adjustabl conf file of patterns, to include some files, on the fly. so here's my example of where I ran into trouble.

Installing software while running on ram, was as simple as doing the normal install, then calling the ramsync to copy-down the changes on the disk. This is quiet a bit faster then doing all the unpacking/twiddling of an install on the disk directly, as you just write the final state down after all the file io is completed. (difference of more than an hour doing a openstack compute node build)

my ramsync's default excludes look like:

```
cat > /tmp/excludes << EOF
/boot/
/boot/*
/dev/*
/dev/pts
/dev/
/media/*
/mnt/
/mnt/*
/proc/*
/proc/
/sys/*
/sys/
/tmp/*
/tmp/
/run/*
/run/
/var/cache/
/var/cache/*
/var/log/
/var/log/*
/var/run/
/var/run/*
/var/lock/
/var/lock/*
/var/tmp/*
/lib/modules/*/volatile/.mounted
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/*
/ramsync/*
/etc/mtab
EOF
```

(/ramsync is the mount-point for the disk in ram)

I used this list via the "--exclude-from '/tmp/excludes'" of rsync. Further reading into rsync's man page led me to believe that the concept of exclude/include was a bit misleading as --exclude-from and --include-from both could include both includes and excludes using the - and + operaters, and include/exclude just implied the default if you didn't include an operator. My reading and what I thought was progress in understanding rsync filter patterns and parsing led me to remake this pattern file as:

```
cat > /tmp/excludes << EOF
- /lib/modules/*/volatile/.mounted
- /etc/apparmor.d/cache/***
- /etc/mtab
- /var/cache/***
- /var/lock/***
- /var/log/***
- /var/run/***
- /var/tmp/***
- /boot/***
- /dev/***
- /media/***
- /mnt/***
- /proc/***
- /sys/***
- /tmp/***
- /ramsync/***
- /run/***
EOF
```

I then tried to apply some includes to this to get some of the files and directories in /var/log/ but only the ones I specified.

All that preamble to ask my question:

How can I both exclude almost all of "/var/log/*" EXCEPT for

/var/log/nova/   (directory)

/var/log/vcos_install.log (file)

I need this file and directory to be saved down.  I know exactly what directories and files I'd like to copy-down and which I'd like to exclude, but I can't figure out what syntax makes sense. I've tried all kinds of combinations of include/exclude patterns and I can't seem to figure out what invocation rsync wants to represent my desired behavior.

I tried adding the following to the top of my /tmp/excludes, but no dice.

```
+ /var/log/vcos_install.log
+ /var/log/nova/***
```

I am reading the man page trying to form this question correctly, and experimenting more, it seems like this should do it, but it doesn't. *Im_confused(rsync)*

```
+ /var
+ /var/log
+ /var/log/vcos_install.log
+ /var/log/nova/
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, in writing this up and doing lots more experiments last night, I figured out that I was close, very close, and had probably been hacking at it too long. The final answer was trailing slashes, and a being-aware-of-recursive-path-traversal include the dir, then later exclude the contents after including the desired subdirectories and file. so what I suggested was -almost- right.

```
+ /var/
+ /var/log/
+ /var/log/vcos_install.log
+ /var/log/nova/
- /var/log/***
```

results when running cmd: 
rsync -ahhsx --progress --delete  --exclude-from '/tmp/filters'  / /ramsync

```
sending incremental file list
./
root/.bash_history
          1.77K 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1456/8825)
var/log/
var/log/vcos_install.log
             82 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=7/68722)
var/log/nova/
```

There are many other files which differ from the destination, on the source, but only the explicitly included directory (/var/log/nova) and my installer log are copied down. This was the mixed exclude/include result I was looking for. Sometimes putting the question together in a coherent format helps solve it.